# Adding Law and Economics as question migration targets in Closing -> Off-topic -> Migration

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, migration

When trying to close an offtopic question, I see only the following option:

> belongs on meta.politics.stackexchange.com discussion, support, and
>   feature requests for this site

From various questions I have seen so far, I think the list can be filled up with the following options:

[Law](https://law.stackexchange.com/) and [Economics](https://economics.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately, [beta sites](https://politics.stackexchange.com/help/whats-beta) do not get custom migration targets.

If you happen upon a question that you think would fare better on a different site, feel free to flag for moderation attention and ask for it to be migrated. Do keep in mind, though, that only high-quality off-topic questions should be migrated. If a question is on-topic on Politics, or if it's not a very good question, your flag may be declined.

Comment: This restriction is quite weird from a practical point of view as it puts extra pressure (effort) on moderators. I think the list can be easily extended and will bring some benefit. Anyway, thanks for quick answer.

Comment: AFAIK exceptions are possible @Alexei. If migrations to Law start taking a considerable amount of our time we could ask SE to give us a custom migration path. Right now though, with only 6 migrations in the past 90 days, that doesn't seem necessary.

Comment: Use Other, and include it as part of your comment.

Answer (score 4):

Mods, can this be reviewed again, now? From what I've observed so far in Po.SE, I recommend adding the following SEs to choose from:

1. Law
2. Economics
3. Skeptics
4. History