# Post Beta Migration Options

Tags: feature-request, migration

Now that the site has moved out of Beta, shouldn't we be getting some custom migration targets as per; [Migration Targets](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2896/adding-law-and-economics-as-question-migration-targets-in-closing-off-topic)

There's a question this morning that could use shifting according to the comments on it, but it gets a lack of consistency in close reasons because the appropriate targets are not listed.

Comment: It's been more than two months since this was raised. Any news on the progress of actually getting at least Law and History as custom question migration targets?

Answer (score 8):

To inform this discussion - during the site's lifespan so far there have been 235 migrations, broken down by site as below (for sites with more than 5 posts migrated).

| Site | Number of Migrations |
| --- | --- |
| Law | 88 |
| History | 37 |
| Politics Meta | 21 |
| Skeptics | 13 |
| Expatriates | 11 |
| Travel | 11 |
| Medical Sciences | 9 |
| Personal Finance & Money | 9 |
| Economics | 8 |
| English Language & Usage | 7 |

Comment: If possible, would you mind adding a couple examples of questions that got migrated to those sites (that is, assuming the information is available to you).

Answer (score 5):

Judging from my own experience of where I migrate questions most often, I think that the most useful migration targets would be:

- [Law](https://law.stackexchange.com/) - for any questions that ask "what is the law" and not "why is this the law". However, we need to be careful to not migrate away any questions that are on-topic because they are about laws which explicitly apply to politicians and political processes. Constitutional law, election regulations, and so on. See also [Where/how do we draw the line between legal and political questions?](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71/where-how-do-we-draw-the-line-between-legal-and-political-questions)
- [History](https://history.stackexchange.com/) - for any questions about events which are so far in the past that they no longer directly affect contemporary politics. See also [Cutoff between Politics and History](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5836/cutoff-between-politics-and-history/5839#5839).