# Add Law Stack Exchange to migrate menu of close votes

Tags: feature-request, migration

I propose we should have the following in Close Menu:

A community-specific reason > This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network > Law Stack Exchange

Law and Politics are sisters.

[It was suggested earlier](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2896/34768)

I considered [editing the previous question](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/2896/4) but it invalidates the existing answer. I [rolled back my edit](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/2896/5)

Then this site was in Beta. Now we are [not beta](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5875/34768)

Comment: Are there so many migrations to Law SE that this specific pathway needs to be added? Are there enough users who understand the topicality of Law SE that they can be trusted with this pathway? Are there really no other priorities needed by Politics SE that this is what needs to pushed for?

Comment: The two sites I migrate most to are History SE and Law SE.

Comment: This question would be improved with recent stats on migrations to Law.SE (and specifically the rejection rate). Users with >2k rep can find that information [here](https://politics.stackexchange.com/tools/posts/migrated/stats).

Comment: @Ian: Judging from that page, there have been 5 migrations in the past 90 days: 4 migrations from Politics to History, and 1 migration from Politics to this Politics Meta site. (It looks like there were no migrations to Law within the last 90 days.)

Answer (score 4):

I don't have any particularly strong feelings either way on this proposal, so I raised it with the Law.SE mods to see what their perspective was - as to create a migration pathway between the two sites we'd need to get agreement from the Law community as well (see [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/379931/) on Meta.SE). Their current view is that they see more drawbacks than benefits to the proposal, and haven't seen enough examples to justify the creation of a custom pathway.

I can see their point somewhat, as in the last year there have been just four migrations to Law.SE, the most recent having [been migrated](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/79868/) over six months ago. That's not to say that the number of migrations might not increase if a custom pathway existed that didn't require moderator action to process, but it does give an idea of the scale of the current situation.

At the moment I'm afraid it doesn't look like this request has sufficient support to implement.

Comment: I do agree that it is not used often but I feel like it would be used more often if there was a migration path and I can see it being useful on the law side as well.

Comment: I wonder how much effort it really is. Sure, it would help only a couple of questions, but if an engineer has to change only a small entry in a database somewhere for it, that is comparable to the effort that we put into a single question to answer it.